# Where to start in the Wordpress codex?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently, I am planning to learn wordpress development. I have a PHP background with professional web development experience, worked on various platforms and frameworks. I have researched alot about best resources for learning wordpress development. I have read few pf the best resources aboit wordpress and I came to know a bit about wordpress flow. A common thing I found is, wordpress codex is recommended as a wordpress bible to become an expert wordpress guru. I have checked out wordpress codex, it seems a bit messy and unstructured in some ways. I want to know that where to start from a wordpress codex first to learn wordpress development fundamentals / basics and afterwards advance development. How to study wordpress codex in a sequence for learning wordpress development? And whats the step by step procedure you guys recommend to start with in wordpress? Just to let you know, I know the overall usage of wordpress software.

Comment: "Begin at the beginning and go on till you come to the end; then stop." - Lewis Carroll

Comment: @Joseph, Lewis Carroll - Is he a wordpress core developer?

Comment: @brokenglass. Thank you - the best comment I have read in ages. I think he'd have made some great contributions to the Wordpress core team.

Comment: Just start building Wordpress sites. You'll find the Codex is superb - an amazing resource that developers on other platforms would give their eye teeth for. Well written, thorough, full of practical examples. You don't get good at karate by reading about karate. Build some Wordpress sites. And read Alice in Wonderland too.

Comment: @MacNab, Thanks alot. Yeah, me too believes that wordpress core is best place to start learning wordpress development :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should start here

When I was back in school professor started on the loop

http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

I did add this here too.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

and do hands on project and then do searches whenever you need to find out how to do something.

Comment: thanks for responding to my question. What should be the overall sequence to be followed for learning plugin and theme development?

Comment: what i posted pretty much covers theme creating, as far as plugin creating then you will need to read the api, hooks/actions documentations but first comes the understand of overall how wordpress works on the basic level i guess.

Comment: Yeah exactly, the wordpress work flow is surely important to understand before getting my hands dirty with the wordpress code. Well, I must appreciate your answer and information in the comment :)